# How to use path range index for JSON doc in marklogic?

Tags: json, marklogic-9

I want use path range query on '/request/datetime'. And the document is JSON.

So which cts function I can use?

Thanks,
Anuj

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using a [`cts.rangeQuery`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.rangeQuery) with a [`cts.pathReference`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.pathReference).

Path range indexes work on both XML and JSON. `/request/datetime` would match both:

```
{
  request: {
    datetime: "my date and time"
  }
}
```

and

```
<request>
  <datetime>my date and time</datetime.
</request>
```

HTH!